# best way to do this string conversion in Python

Tags: python

I need to convert a string to another which has removed anything before the second word

Example from this,

```
string = "xyz anything else"
string2 = "xyz  anything else"
string3 = "xyz   anything else"
```

to this,

```
string = "anything else" 
string2 = "anything else"
string3 = "anything else"
```

The way I've done it doesnt please me at all, it isnt pythonic and it's too large. What it would be the best way to do it in Python?

Comment: it would be nice if you shared with everyone your original solution, even if "it isnt pythonic and it's too large," as i think it'll help everyone. nice solution below though from jcd/kaizer.se! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s.split(None, 1)[-1]
```

Comment: If you want `"singleword".split(None, 1)` to be safe, better use `-1` index (last item) since the result might not always have length two. If you prefer an error in this case, the present solution is just fine.